# Julia: Passing Multiple Arguments to Anonymous Functions

Tags: arguments, anonymous-function, julia

In the Julia Manual under the [Anonymous Functions section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#anonymous-functions) one of the examples that is offered is `(x,y,z)->2x+y-z`.

Could someone please show me how one would pass a set of arguments to this function?

Say `x=(1,2,3); y=(2,3,4); z=(1,3,5)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you define x,y and z to be arrays then you can just call the function and pass them in:

```
fun = (x,y,z)->2x+y-z
x=[1,2,3]
y=[2,3,4]
z=[1,3,5]
fun(x, y, z)
```

giving the result:

```
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
 5
```

But if you want to do this with tuples, as per your example, you will need to use map:

```
x=(1,2,3)
y=(2,3,4)
z=(1,3,5)
map(fun, x, y, z)
```

this gives the same result, but this time as a tuple:

```
(3, 4, 5)
```

This is because the *, + and - operators are not defined for tuples so the formula `2x+y-z` can't work. Using `map` gets around this by calling the function multiple times passing in scalars.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign the anonymous function to a variable, in order to call it.

```
julia> fun = (x,y,z)->2x+y-z
(anonymous function)

julia> fun((1,2,3),(2,3,4),(1,3,5))
ERROR: no method *(Int64, (Int64,Int64,Int64))
 in anonymous at none:1
```

It does not work, because the tuples you set for `x`, does not implement the `*` function.

Comment: I see.  I am going to need to get more experience with Julia.  An alternative way not requiring assignment is `((x,y,z)->2x+y-z)(1,2,3)`

Comment: Yes, that is also possible.